# Can I fill an android app form in code by decompiling it?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I want to fill android forms in android App's code itself.

For example: An App requires email and name. While the App is opening I want to fill details in by decompiling that App and filling in the respective email and name fields in code itself and compiling it again so it can directly fetch from code itself.

Is something like this possible??

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. You cannot replace the user's installed app with your hacked version, as they will not be signed by the same signing key.